# Показывать подсказки при введении алиаса

Tags: bash, консоль

Есть к примеру вот такой алиас

`alias defmig='dotnet ef migrations add'`

на простую миграцию в dotnet!

Давно такая идея появилась но ничего не нашёл

Суть в следующем: 
Я хочу что бы при введении алиаса появлялись подсказки.
Ну наподобие чего то такого к примеру.

Вводим `defmig` после команды появлялась строка подсказки, каким нибудь серым цветом, мол введите названия миграции!

`defmig` *(enter name your migrations)*

ну и при наведении курсора естественно надпись исчезала, на подобии ввода email или что то такого.

Можно ли сделать что то такое с помощью bash может там есть такой механизм? Или кто то знает похожую фичу?

**Это не должно работать по TAB это должно появляться как подсказка на подобии как в fish-shell только что появиться должен я контролировать.**

Comment: в bash'е можно сделать только (затратив разумные усилия) дополнения по tab'у... нечто подобное есть у `zsh`: выводить список вариантов автодополнения в консоль...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Посмотрю Спасибо!

Comment: Это называется bash-completion. Вы там просто можете прописать правила, какие параметры надо передавать, но примеры "серым цветом" показать не получится.

Comment: @Axenow По моему то что нужно! А, ссылок по подробней почитать нет случаем?

Comment: если нужно все из коробки - `fish-shell`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нет это не дубликат.